# Why isn't this scaling working?

Tags: javascript, math

Currently I am trying to scale a data to a size to fit between two numbers. My code is as below:

```
function dataScaling(db,rangeMax,rangeMin,value) {

  var min = db[1].FIELD1;
  var max = min;

  for (var i=2; i < db.length; i++) {
    if (db[i].FIELD1 < min) {min = db[i].FIELD1;}
    if (db[i].FIELD1 > max) {max = db[i].FIELD1;}
  }

  var percent = (value - min) / (max - min);
  var answer = percent * (rangeMax - rangeMin) + rangeMin;
  return answer;

}
```

Now when I run:

```
console.log("Min = "+min);
console.log("Maz = "+max);
```

and `if (answer > rangeMax) {console.log("Value is Too BIG: "+answer );}`, I get:

```
Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
index.js:171 Value is Too BIG: 57.38461538461539
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
index.js:171 Value is Too BIG: 49.07692307692308
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
index.js:171 Value is Too BIG: 29.692307692307693
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 6500000
```

The very first time and for the second time, I get:

```
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
index.js:171 Value is Too BIG: 139.14285714285714
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
index.js:171 Value is Too BIG: 96.28571428571429
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
index.js:171 Value is Too BIG: 87.71428571428571
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
index.js:166 Min = 0
index.js:167 Maz = 21000000
```

It must be noted that the input to `dataScaling` function (`db`) is constantly changing every time I run the program. What I don't understand, is the data exceeding the ranges. I call the function using this:

```
dataScaling(initialArray,20,2,d.FIELD1);
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You haven't exactly made it clear (a) what kind of thing you're inputting, and (b) what kind of thing you expect out of your function.

Comment: @TKoL I'm not really sure how I have not made it clear. I have explained that I am scaling values from a given range of a random input to a target range of my desire. The console logs are also explicitly shown.

Comment: I didn't downvote, for the record.

Comment: Anyway, it's unclear what the actual problem is. You present it to us like it's a problem with your algorithm, but based on the console logs it looks like something weird, like the greater-than operator is producing the wrong results or something, because obviously `139.14285714285714` is not greater than `21000000`. There just isn't enough information to understand hwat's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but I think this is your solution.

```js
/** 
 * Re-maps a number from one range to another.
 * @param {number} value Value to be converted.
 * @param {number} min1 Lower bound of the value's current range.
 * @param {number} max1 Upper bound of the value's current range.
 * @param {number} min2 Lower bound of the value's target range.
 * @param {number} max2 Upper bound of the value's target range.
 * @returns {number}
 */ 
function Map(value, min1, max1, min2, max2) {
    return ((value - min1) / (max1 - min1)) * (max2 - min2) + min2;
}

// Lets say this is percentiles
let foo = 25;

// You want the percentiles to a scale from 0 to 2
let doo = Map(foo, 0, 100, 0, 2)
console.log(doo);

// From the scale 0-2 back to percentiles.
console.log(Map(doo, 0, 2, 0, 100));
```

Answer (score 0):

You never say or check that `d.FIELD1` (i.e. `value` argument) is within `min` and `max`.

BTW, what about `db[0].FIELD1`?